# ElasticSearch/Logstash 5 - rename .raw to .keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

we updated ELK from 2.4 to 5.x, which was pretty much successful. However, when new indices were created logstash started to use the [new naming convention](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/breaking-changes.html#_elasticsearch_output_index_template) for not analyzed field. So indices from before the update use `.raw` and since the update `.keyword`, which is difficult for the use in Kibana ;)

I read some documents of how to solve that, but don't quite get it. One suggestion was to use the reindex api of ES and rename .raw, but as mentioned I am not quite sure how that would work. I could live with copying `.raw` to `.keyword` instead of renaming it as well.

The data is mostly apache-logs with ~500 indices.

I would very much appreciate an easy solution and, if possible, even with the start of an example how to bulk-process that

---

**EDIT:**

I ended up reindexing everything via logstash (elasticsearch as input and output plugin). Maybe that can be of use for someone ..

Answer (score 0):

Export your objects from version 2.4, rename all `.raw` to `.keyword` and import it back to 5.x.